# Using Swift and SwiflyJSON to write to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having trouble getting SwiftlyJSON to edit JSON variables, is it possible to get it to write and actually edit the file? I want it to create new arrays. The way I would do it in JavaScript would be

```
json.blocks.x = [];
json.blocks.x[0].y = [];
json.blocks.x[0].y[0].id = 4
```

It would create some new arrays into that.
How would I recreate this in Swift? Preferably SwiftlyJSON?

Please help!

Comment: I don't think this is possible with SwiftyJSON. I think the best bet is for you to work with a Dictionary and then convert it to json with JSON(dictionary: dictionary) or something of that nature.

Comment: I've tried using SwiftyJSON, and it never worked. The best way to do it is how @David said.

Comment: Don't Use 3rd party libraries. Swift is completely flexible for JSON. If you interest please refer [my videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBhTZf-4NZo&list=PLT7YNwQNKSPAlf-G12qRzHlw3mwJ0g62s&index=6)